# Что нужно сделать в этом вопросе?

Tags: openserver

> 2018-04-24 17:26:08  --------------------------------------------
>   2018-04-24 17:26:08  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
>   2018-04-24 17:26:09  Файл C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts недоступен для записи
>   2018-04-24 17:26:09  Отключите использование HOSTS файла или настройте права доступа
>   2018-04-24 17:26:09  Сбой запуска!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается запуском Open Server от Администратора. В крайнем случае перезагрузкой ПК с дальнейшем запуском OS от администратора.